# mongodb aggregate match two fields

Tags: mongodb, match, aggregate

A stage in an aggregation pipeline produce the following collection:

```
{
    _id : {
        airport : "SGF",
        minEffect : "security_delay",
        delayType : "arr_delay",
    }
}
{
    _id : {
        airport : "MIA",
        minEffect : "weather_delay",
        delayType : "weather_delay",
    }
}
{
...
}
```

I want to reduce the documents in the collection and to get only the documents where the value of `minEffect` equal to the value of `delayed Type`.

Why the following code doesn't work?

```
{$match:{"_id.delayType":"$_id.minEffect"}}
```

In reference to the sample above, the expected result need to be as follows:

```
{
    _id : {
        airport : "MIA",
        minEffect : "weather_delay",
        delayType : "weather_delay",
    }
}
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like following.

```
{
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$_id.minEffect",
          "$_id.delayType"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SN67mql5bmV)